# MATLAB: how to delete elements of cell array A from cell array B?

Tags: string, matlab, cell-array

I have two cell arrays of strings `A` and `B` that hold 60 and 400 subject names, respectively. All the subjects in cell array `A` are also in cell array `B`. What I would like to do is to delete the subjects listed in cell array `A` from cell array `B` to arrive at cell array `C`, that holds only the subjects I want to work with.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't care about the result being sorted, you can use the function [SETDIFF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/setdiff.html):

```
C = setdiff(B, A);
```

If you need the result in the same order as the original cell array `B` with the names from `A` removed, you can use the function [ISMEMBER](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html):

```
C = B(~ismember(B, A));
```

**UPDATE:** In newer versions of MATLAB, an additional argument has been added to [SETDIFF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/setdiff.html) to control the output element sorting. To maintain the original order, you can now do this:

```
C = setdiff(B, A, 'stable');
```

Comment: Great answer as always, I didn't know about the setdiff function. Mike—as you clearly like it, you can click the up arrow by the answer, and click the tick box below it. This is a more formal way of giving 'thanks' to the answerer.